# French playing cards, probability to have a four (of a kind)

Tags: probability

We have a "French playing cards" composed of $52$ cards. Each kind of cards (Ace, King, Queen, ...) is composed of $4$ cards :  There are $4$ Ace, $4$ Jack, etc. We pull $5$ cards among the $52$ cards.

We are a *four (of a kind)* if among the $5$ cards pulled, there are the $4$ of a same value ($4$ cards Ace, or King, or 2, or 3......).

[image]

What is the probability to have a *four (of a kind)* if the first card pulled is an Ace, and the fifth card pulled is a King ?

I hope you understand, it's very difficult for me to translate that. Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: In English, As is Ace, Valet is Jack or Knave, Dame is Queen and Roi is King.

Comment: Thank you, I edit immediately !

Comment: Some more English terminology: For the four of hearts (*quatre coeurs?*), the four is called the *rank* of the card, and hearts is called the *suit* of the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint:

Given that you have drawn one ace and one king, you will need *either* to draw the remaining three aces, *or* draw the remaining three kings, from the remaining $50$ cards.

Can you continue from this point?

(Spoiler answer)

> There are two winning ways to draw the remaining three cards, and ${50 \choose 3}$ total ways to draw the remaining three cards, so the probability is $2/{50 \choose 3}$.

Comment: I try it, thank you :)